# Convolve with a box filter in time domain

Tags: filters, convolution, frequency, fourier

To low pass filter a signal, we have to convolve it with a sinc function because it's the same as multiplying the Fourier transform of the signal with a rect function, resulting in the high frequency of the signal cut off, thus blurring the signal.

Now I hear people talking about "box filters" and saying that by convolving a signal with a box filter, we blur the signal. But a box filter is nothing but a rect function! So now I'm confused, the blurring comes from the fact that we remove the high frequencies of the signal (by multiplying the frequencies by a rect, or convoling with a sinc), but why on earth convolving with a box filter (a rect function) achieve the effect of blurring? What theorem of signal processing are we talking about here?

Comment: You can't convolve with a sinc() functions since it's infinitely long and infinitely non-causal. The real world doesn't work this way

Comment: It seems to me that you (or the people you are listening to) are confusing "box" in the frequency domain and "box" in the time domain (moving average).

Also, note that multiplying with a box in the frequency domain will only give you the expected result for the frequencies corresponding to the DFT points, not for any intermediate frequencies. So you need an infinitely long DFT to get that, so no can do.

Answer (score 2):

A box filter, like many other filters, has a low-pass characteristic. The box filter is really bad at it though, the reason people use it is because it is so easy to implement and so cheap to compute.

In the frequency domain, the box filter is a sinc. Higher frequencies are attenuated, but the filter goes to zero very, very slowly, thus not attenuating higher frequencies as well as other low-pass filters. Additionally, the sinc has regions where it is negative. Those frequencies are inverted. If you sample a sine wave, and take a box filter that is a little larger than one period (best effect 1.5 periods in width), you will see that the filtered signal is a sine with a 180 degree shift in phase. It has maxima where the input has minima.

Applying a box filter twice is equivalent to convolving with a triangular filter. In the frequency domain, it is a squared sinc, and consequently it doesn’t have negative regions, and it goes to zero more quickly. In the limit to infinite applications of the box filter, one obtains a Gaussian filter, which is an optimal filter in terms of compactness in both the spatial and the frequency domain.

Answer (score 0):

> To low pass filter a signal, we have to convolve it with a sinc function

Well, no.  There's an infinite number of filters that have a low-pass characteristic.  The term "low pass filter" means any filter that passes low-frequency signal components with minimal attenuation and attenuates high-frequency signal components with significant attenuation.  Most low-pass filters have a high-frequency characteristic that trends to more attenuation as the frequency goes up, but this is optional (see "eliptical filter").

> because it's the same as multiplying the Fourier transform of the signal with a rect function, resulting in the high frequency of the signal cut off.

There's terminology involved in this, so "because" is a strong word.  Certainly because the high-frequency components are attenuated and the low-frequency components aren't.  I certainly don't think of a low-pass filter in terms of the Fourier transform -- that's a derived characteristic.  I think of it in terms of allowing low frequency components through and blocking high ones.

> thus blurring the signal.

"Blurring" is an odd choice of words unless you're talking about images.  Images or no, if the signal is slowly varying, then a low-pass filter can be chosen that does not affect the signal much.

> ... but why on earth convolving with a box filter (a rect function) achieve the effect of blurring? What theorem of signal processing are we talking about here?

No theorem per se.  Take the Fourier transform of a moving-average (i.e. "box") filter and plot it -- or measure the actual response to a sine wave and plot that.  It has a gain of 1 at DC, and at any frequency higher than $f = 0$ the gain will be smaller.

For a moving average filter of length $T$, it has a gain of $\frac{2}{\pi n}$ at a frequency of $f = \frac{1}{2T}, \frac{3}{2T}, \frac{5}{2T}, \cdots$: choose any such point, and at any frequency higher, the gain will be strictly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Low-pass filters globally show up in the frequency domain as having:

- relatively high magnitude near the 0-frequency or DC,
- relatively low magnitude near the "Nyquist" or highest frequency,
- not too high magnitude "on average" in the middle.

In other words, we expect that the lower frequency are better preserved (little attenuation) than higher ones. A struct decrease of the spectrum is not mandatory, yet very of the the local maxima of the amplitude spectrum are expected to almost decrease.

The sinc filter provides an example of this: piecewise constant at 1, then zero. For the box filter, the discrete Fourier transform looks like a sinc (a periodic or aliased sinc), so globally the local maxima are somehow decreasing. It is also considered as a low-pass filter.

Yet, it can be easier to understand it this way:

1. a linear combination of samples of a sine at some frequency will be a sine at the same frequency, only with a different amplitude (maybe zero) and phase
2. a uniform averager or box filter $1/K[1_1,\,1_2,...,\,1_K]$ yields a result that is always lower or equal to the maximum in a window (and higher or equal to the minium). Thus the sine will be of lower or equal amplitude after filtering.
3. the longer the box filter, the more chances to have small samples in the window that diminishes the filtering outcome. However, it depends a lot on how well the window encompasses periods of the sine.